# I run a full monero node, is there a way to see my node on the network? Can I mark my node some how?

Tags: full-node

I'm running a monero full node. Is there a way to see my node on the network? Is there a way to label my node that others can also see it. Say i wanted to label it as: "Free Open Monero v13 Node"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Nodes are just identified by IP addresses.